# Attach to a domain when running EC2 instance

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, sdk

I try to attach a new instance with my Domain with the .Net AWS SDK like we can do with the Web interface.

Today I use this code:

```
       var launchRequest = new RunInstancesRequest()
            {
                ImageId = amiID,
                InstanceType = InstanceType.G4dn2xlarge,
                MinCount = 1,
                MaxCount = 1,
                KeyName = keyPairName,
                SecurityGroupIds = groups,
                
                IamInstanceProfile = instanceProfile,
                
            };

            var launchResponse = ec2Client.RunInstancesAsync(launchRequest).Result;
```

But I don't find any fields about domain into RunInstancesRequest class.

Do you have any idea to join domain when we create instance with .net SDK?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are referring to a DNS domain. DNS domains are managed by [Route53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/). So if you are using the .NET SDK you have to use the Route53 client.

An example is described in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/route53-apis-intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

my question concerns the use of this field progammaticly with the SDK

[image: Domain join with interface]